# MySQL connection works for Workbench but not Tomcat Application using same credentials

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am working on a remote Redhat system over SSH. `Tomcat 7` and `MySQL 5.5` server are both installed and appear to be running correctly.

I can connect to MySQL from a local install of `Workbench over SSH tunneling` using `localhost` and a defined MySQL user.  I can run queries and navigate tables without incident.

When I try to connect to the same MySQL Server with a Tomcat application running in the same environment using the MySQL defined user (`same credentials`) that Workbench is connecting with successfully, **it fails**.

At this point I don't know the exact error message that gets generated (I am not an admin) so any guidance here is appreciated.

My question is why can I connect with Workbench (which is effectively connecting locally), but not with my Tomcat application, which actually is local to the server?

Might it be a permissions issue with the context Tomcat is running under?

**References:**

Connection string example (credentials have been altered):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql_database_name?user=ApplicationUsername&password=ApplicationPassword"
```

Furthermore, I have verified that

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
```

is in the WEB-INF folder, and:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

resolves.

**This web application works in both dev and test on another server connecting using respective credentials.**

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the port number of mysql server exists in connection string. Normally if port is not specified, default value would be used as 3306. Maybe your mysql runs on different port?

jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...

If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.

Comment: I will try that.  However, MySQL is using default port 3306 on server giving me grief and I don't specify a port in dev or test environments with successful connections respectively.

Comment: Maybe mysql is not allowing connections from "@'localhost' (using password yes)". You may need to update privileges.

Comment: But that is what Workbench is using to connect!?  Does Workbench get special privileges that no other process does not?

Comment: Are your workbench running on the same machine with mysql server? Maybe you are using IP address on workbench? I am just thinking out loud.

Comment: No - Workbench is `local` and connecting via SSH tunneling - so it connects effectively as a local process.  It's using the `@localhost` to resolve the server.